# Why NextAuth with Facebook provider is getting 500 Server Error?

Tags: facebook, next.js, oauth, next.js13, next-auth

I'm building an app in NextJS 13.5 and using NextAuth 4.23. I've successfully added Github's OAuth login, but haven't been able to use Facebook as such.

After creating and app in Facebook Developer console, added App ID, client secret to `.env` and my localhost URL to `Website > Site URL` section
[image]

I'm getting 500 page on auth attempt.

[image]

I don't think any of these would need to be configured though:

[image]

Comment: _"I don't think any of these would need to be configured though"_ - no, but if this component is using the server-side login flow, then your Valid OAuth Redirect URIs would need to be configured in the app settings.